# 電話帳のテーブル設計

Tags: database, oracle

```
ユーザ毎に電話番号を登録します。
ユーザは複数の電話帳を登録できて、上記の登録済みの電話番号を電話帳に登録できます。
電話番号は、複数の電話帳に登録が可能です。
```

としたい時のテーブル設計で悩んでいます。

今のところは、電話帳テーブルのユニークなIDをtag的に電話番号に付与しようと思っています。
ただ、そうすると、tagカラムの文字列長が気になっちゃったり、CLOB使うか？とか思っちゃったり、悩みどころが多くて困っています。
もちろん電話帳から電話番号を絞りこんだりしたいです。

イメージ的には、スマホなどのアドレス帳で、1つの連絡先に複数のグループを指定できるというのが近い感じだと思います。

こういう多対多のようなデータ設計って、どうしてやるのが良いんでしょうか？
今回以外でも似たような状況があったんですが...その時は紐付けテーブル(電話帳と電話番号を結び付けるだけのテーブル)が用意されていました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

もし私が実装するなら、ユーザーは複数の電話番号を持てるのかどうか、仕様確認すると思います。
複数持てるとするならば、「ユーザー、番号、電話帳」の3つが実体を持つデータで、それぞれを中間テーブルで繋げば良いのかと思いました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: やっぱし連携する中間テーブル作る方が良いんですかね...?
連携の数だけ中間テーブルにレコードが増えるのを躊躇してしまって、今の方法を検討しました。

Comment: なるほど。SQLアンチパターンはお調べになられましたでしょうか。もしかするとこの辺りが参考になるかもしれません[SQLアンチパターン - 1章 Jaywalking(信号無視) - Qiita](http://qiita.com/iwata@github/items/f33490d34dd1400b166e)。

Comment: SQLのアンチパターンは調べた事なかったです。勉強になります。
こちらのページも参考にさせていただいて再検討してみます。